# How to Configure Visual Studio to Build Angular project as well as part of Build

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, visual-studio

Every time we need to goto ClientApp folder and type npm install manually.
But in different projects - Visual Studio template project it this build happens out of box.

What configuration are required?

What I tried: I did install following nuget package: But id didn't help either.

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.5.3">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new project in Visual Studio using the ASP.NET Core app with Angular template ([learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022)), then search for the "npm" string in its .csproj  files. You'll find something like this:

```
<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />

<!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
<ItemGroup>
  <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
  <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
    <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```